# What is the difference between Login-AzureRmAccount and Connect-AzureRmAccount?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

I tried to google this, but despite of many promising item in the search list, all of them are about ARM vs ASM or Add-AzureRmAccount vs Connect-AzureRmAccount.

Both are ARM commands, and both pops up the interactive login.
Maybe I am missing the point, but I do found the difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No difference, one is the alias of the other, as far as I remember. they attempt to migrate to a unified experience across powershell modules (like Azure AD, Office 365, etc).

Comment: If you `Get-Help Add-AzureRmAccount` it gives the help for `Connect-AzureRmAccount`, so yeah :)

Comment: juunas - OP specifically asked about "Install-" vs. "Connect-" and even more importantly stated that there was not an interest in "Add-" as there were plenty of sources for that information already.